# do until/while with set statement in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, do-while

I am looking for an example of do until/while used with set statement except Dow loop like below.

```
data want;
  set have;
    do until/while (exit criteria);
     * some SAS statements;
    end;
run;
```

I had originally tried this one.

```
data test;
  input x;
  cards;
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ;
 run;

data test2;
   set test;
     count = 0;
       do until (count >= 3);
         y = x + count;
         count + 1 ;
        output;
       end;
  run;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. "Example of DoW loop" is not a question. What are you trying to do?  The code you have shown is not a DoW loop. A DoW loop would have the set statement inside the DO loop.

Comment: Quentin. I am not asking an example of dow loop. I should have removed the dow loop part from question.   I know in dow loop set statement is inside do loop. The example I provided generates records for each observation read from input data set. Under which scenarios this type of looping would be useful?

Comment: Still don't understand the question.  It's useful in a scenario when you want to generate multiple records for each observation. For example, you have a dataset of patient IDs, and want to make a dataset that has 10 records for each patient, for visit=1 to visit=10.

Comment: This makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data whatdidyoutry;
  set sashelp.class;
  f=2;
  wt=1;
  do until (wt=f);
    wt+1;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: I could not put code in the add comment box. So I did edit my question.

Comment: The concern I have is for every observation read from input data set, new records will be created until a condition is met. This is like generating data.

Comment: so..  what is your question?

Comment: I think I got the answer. Thanks.